# What is Happening in this C++ Code? Why s.u.a = 20?

Tags: c++, struct, unions

I was expecting the output to look like: `10 20 10 20`

But the output came like this: `10 20 20 20`

What is happening behind the code?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct sdata{
    int a;
    int b;
    union udata{
        int a;
        int b;
    }u;
}Data;

int main()
{
    Data s;
    s.a = 10;
    s.b = 20;
    s.u.a = 10;
    s.u.b = 20;
    cout << s.a << " " << s.b << " " << s.u.a << " " << s.u.b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on what unions do. You seem to be using them, but expecting them to behave like structs.

Comment: What makes you believe that it should be `10`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike a `struct`, a `union` can only hold one member at a time.  Each member starts at the same memory address, so writing to one affects the other.

In this case your union has two fields of type `int`.  So if you set one than the other will contain exactly the same value.  So when you set `s.u.b` to 20 it also sets `s.u.a` to that value as well.